# Average and Mean in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, average, mean

I used already numpy.mean and numpy.average for the csv file that i opened but now i wanted to do it since 1 week ago but there is a strange result. when i use my calculator give me something else than python.

```
import socket
import numpy as np
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind(('192.168.0.1', 2015))
for message in range(0, 5):

    message =sock.recv(2048)
    print message.split()[0]
print np.average((map(float, message.split())))

sock.close()
```

in fifth and sixth line I take five numbers from another laptop (like a column) and i want to calculate mean of that column. I do it with line number 9 and result is not mean of that five number. btw in python numbers are in scientific notation.

4769288
4769289
4769290
4769291
4769292

*397444.993724* (result that numpy.average gave)

first five numbers are numbers that come from socket and last number is the mean that python calculated.but right number should be **4769290**

waiting for your help and idea

Comment: Show some example data, expected result and actual result.

Comment: 4769288
4769289
4769290
4769291
4769292
397444.993724

Comment: @PadraicCunningham if i remove `split()` give me error like : **could not convert string to float**

Comment: @kian, keep the split but show exactly what it returns

Comment: @tobias_k there is a big different between number that came out from numpy.average with right one

Comment: @PadraicCunningham i am relly sorry but i dont understand what are you talking about.can you tell me how should i do it?

Comment: @tobias_k i tried right now. no different

Comment: @kian, I mean just `print message.split()` so we can see exactly what you get when you split

Comment: @PadraicCunningham ok. this is the result :  ['5019449', '1.52000000000e-06', '9.00000000000e-08', '-2.45000000000e-07', '0', '-3.79960000000e-04', '-7.98800000000e-04', '-4.95445600000e-02', '0', '4.80937500000e+01', '5.00100000000e-03', '5.04500000000e-03']

Comment: for that input what average do you get and does that output match up with where you get your data from?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham ok. this is the result :  ['5019449', '5019450','5019451','5019452','5019453'] but numbers are different with 10 min ago.because i took new numbers from server.

Comment: I cannot replicate,  add a few examples of what `spl = message.split();print(spl);print(np.average(map(float, spl)))` outputs to your question putting the average call in the loop

Comment: Okay, I think I know what's the problem: You have that loop, that loops five times. Each time, you print the first number that you get from the server (i.e. the 1st, 11th, 21th, ..., 51th number, assuming batches of 10 numbers), but then (_after_ the loop) you calculate the average for the last batch of numbers (i.e. the 51th to 60th number). Is this what you actually want to do?

Comment: @tobias_k maybe yes but let me i tell u maybe understand it better : everytime i run my program, i want to habe 5 number that i have them easily.but now i want to find mean of them that it give me wrong answer. if you understood it either right or wrong give mw your idea please

Comment: @kian, you are not storing any numbers, you just use the very last value of message from your loop.  Every time you use `message =..` you reassign the name to a new value, it does not store all the values

Comment: @PadraicCunningham i am sorry but they are the things that i fount on internet and without them program give me very strange errors. about examples i gave you.

Comment: @kian, if you want the first number from each `message.split()`, you need to store all those in some container initialised outside the loop i.e a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> in fifth and sixth line I take five numbers from another laptop (like a column) and i want to calculate mean of that column. I do it with line number 9

No, you don't. What you *actually* do: You *print* the numbers from that column, but then take the average of the last *row* instead! Try this:

```
column = []
for _ in range(5):
    message = sock.recv(2048)
    column.append(message.split()[0])
print np.average((map(float, column)))
```

Comment: Or 
`columns = [float(sock.recv(2048).split()[0]) ]for _ in range(5)]`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Sure, I did not want to alter too much to make clear what's the actual problem. ;-)

Comment: Yep, it is almost certainly the problem, I thought the print was indented incorrectly but reading the question again it seems it is not

Comment: @tobias_k you are the best. can you just help me for last question.your code give me the mean but at the same time i want to see the 5 numbers too but it doesnt show me.

Comment: @kian If you also want to see those numbers, just restore the `print message.split()[0]`, but also keep the `column.append(...)` line! Or just do `print column` after the loop.